# Trying to Make an Alphabetical Converter With JavaScript Arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, forms, converters, alphabetical

I'm trying to create some alternative "languages" for a roleplaying game that I administer. It's a simple character substitution, although in some places one character can be replaced with multiple. How can I do this with JavaScript arrays?

Some examples:

1. Elemental

   ```
   a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z

   r n a y f z d u h g t e q b w m i v o k l x j c s p

   A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z

   R N A Y F Z D U H G T E Q B W M I V O K L X J C S P
   ```
2. Orcish

   ```
   a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z

   c w r p o d y a e b x g k z h q v u s m l j f n t i

   A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z

   C W R P O D Y A E B X G K Z H Q V U S M L J F N T I
   ```
3. Magi's Tongue

   ```
   a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z

   coa taj nel sa jo yin p g d w m hep qoi uxo lso bei ilok abi zel rol kef fas oel ero ve xo

   A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z

   COA TAJ NEL SA JO YIN P G D W M HEP QOI UXO LSO BEI ILOK ABI ZEL ROL KEF FAS OEL ERO VE XO
   ```

Comment: Your question was a _gigantic_ wall of text which I've now edited down to a more sensible form. You need to be concise and explain your question clearly instead of rambling, otherwise people aren't going to read your question let alone answer it. Please edit your question in it's shortened form if I've left out any crucial details

Comment: _Even some of my professional coding friends who know some JavaScript have literally told me to stay away from it, unless I wanted a massive headache._ -- you should meet some real programmers...

Answer (score 0):

Try something like that

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var lang = {
    normal : {
            'a':0,
            'b':1,
            'c':2,
            'd':3}, 
    elemental : ['r','n','a','y'],
    orkish : ['c','w','r','p'],
    magis : ['coa','taj','nel','sa']
};

console.log('Normal : bbc');
var _str = 'bbc';

var translate = '';
for(i = 0; i <= _str.length - 1;i++)
{   
    var t = _str[i];
    translate += lang['elemental'][lang['normal'][t]];
}

console.log(translate);


var translate = '';
for(i = 0; i <= _str.length - 1;i++)
{   
    var t = _str[i];
    translate += lang['magis'][lang['normal'][t]];
}
    console.log(translate);

 </script>
```

Result in browser console (for example chrome - f12) :

Normal    : bbc

Elemental : nna

Magis     : tajtajnel

Comment: Thank you very much Slash, it means a lot. Your time is greatly appreciated!